# Populate a case class from a DB ResultSet

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following code that I am using to retrieve data from a database and then populate a class.

If the column names and the class properties are identical is there a more elegant way of populating the class other than the two step process I currently have - of (1) creating variables and then (2) populating the object with the variables?

As you can appreciate when the class has many properties - there is a lot of doubled-up code to be typed that I would like to avoid.

**Updated :**
Thanks for the suggestion to use Doobie / Anorm / etc. : But I deliberately want to hand write the persistence layer as a Scala / FP learning exercise.
it is also my understanding that macros are changing in Scala 3 - which isn't too far away, now - so I'd rather have a solution that is applicable after the upgrade; Thanks!

```
def getGroups(): Vector[Group] = {

    def createGroup(groupname: String) = {
      Group(groupName = groupname
            ...
            ...
            ...
      )
    }

    // Get the rows returned from the database.
    val dbResults = Try { selectAllFromTable("groups") }

    dbResults match {
      case Success(rs) => {
        // Create an Iterator[]
        ResultSetUtils.toIterator(rs) { rs =>
          createGroup(
            rs.getString("groupname")
            ...
            ...
            ...
          )
        }
      }.toVector

      case Failure(ex) =>
        Vector.empty[Group]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Firat, the 'createGroup' function is unnecessary. Than, you can use reflection or macros to avoid boilerplate.  However,  you should choose  a library,  that already provides this for you. Someone will give you a good list of suggestions for sure. I only used Hibernate for Java and ScalikeJDBC for Scala.

Comment: You can check out https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/

Comment: Or https://playframework.github.io/anorm/

Comment: Depending on what approach you prefer: Slick if you use Akka and Lightbend stack, Doobie and/or Quill for Cats and FP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ygor,

I finally worked out what you were saying and got rid of the createGroup method. which of course meant I was no longer "double-typing" the case class creation and population.

Now I just have;

```
def getGroups(): Vector[Group] = {

    // Get the rows returned from the database.
    val dbResults = Try { selectAllFromTable("groups") }

    dbResults match {
      case Success(rs) => {
        // Create an Iterator[]
        ResultSetUtils.toIterator(rs) { rs =>
          Group(
            rs.getString("groupname")
            ...
            ...
            ...
          )
        }
      }.toVector

      case Failure(ex) =>
        Vector.empty[Group]
    }
  }
```